# Outputting Japanese Characters to a File using Python

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, utf-8, teradata

**Goal** --> I am trying to automate the query execution process using *Python*

**Detail** --> My Source is *Teradata* Database and Destination is *.txt* file

I am writing a Python code  to run a query in Teradata and save the output in .txt file.

**Issue** --> Even though,I am able to run the query and save the output,The Japanese Character are showing up as "\x1a\x1a"

For ex . when i run the query the output i see in Teradata SQL Assistant window is "愛してる”　 while the output in text file is "\x1a\x1a"
I am using "PYCharm" for coding
I am using below code for writing the file

```
#!/usr/bin/env python  
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-  
import io  
import pyodbc  
import os  

#Establish connection with Teradata  
conn = pyodbc.connect('Coneection Parameters')  
conn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')  
cur = conn.cursor()  
conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')

#Reading Query  
scriptFile = open('query.sql','r')  
script = scriptFile.read()  
scriptFile.close()  

#Executing Query  
cur.execute(script)  
rows = cur.fetchall()  

#Writing the output to file  
with open('results.txt','w') as f:  
   print(rows)  
   f.write('%s\n' % rows)  

#Closing the Connection  
cur.close()#close the query writing  
conn.close()
```

The variables used
**results.txt** -> Target File,where i want to write the Japanese Character

Sample Output I am expecting **ペット用品**

The Output I am getting in File "results.txt" --> **[('\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a\x1a', )]**

Comment: Please make sure the code you post is correct and properly indented. In this code, `f` is undefined, and both `for` and the next row are not indented correctly. Additionally, because it is about encoding, please tag with [tag:python2] or [tag:python3], and give us exact contents of both at least one row, and the output file. There is zero chance that `"愛してる"` becomes `"\x1a\x1a\x1a"` - `\x1a` is a substitute character (usually for encoding error), but `"愛してる"` has four characters, and you have three substitute characters. Also indicate which encoding you wish for the file (UTF-8? SJIS? EUCJP?)

Comment: Thanks for adding comments,

Comment: I can't see any way for Python3 to produce such output if the string was correct in the first place, so either I'm missing something, or I'd guess reading from the database is the problem, not the output.

Comment: Is the database actually configured to store and return its results in UTF-8?

Comment: Is the actual bug that `rows` and `row` are two completely different variables, or is your script still missing an essential part?

Comment: @tripleee , the row was typo, I corrected it    
Is the database actually configured to store and return its results in UTF-8?  Yes,I can export Data in using database by running the query in SQL Assistant.

Comment: `\x1a` is simply the Esc character. Proper Unicode has a distinct character [U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) for replacing characters which were invalid or unrepresentable.

Comment: If you don't *know* the encoding used by the database, perhaps explain that instead of answering unrelated tangential questions. "I can export" is unremarkable and says nothing about the actual encoding of the data you are able to retrieve.

Answer (score 9):

Let's solve the title problem.  To output Japanese (or any language) to a file:

1. Start with a Unicode string.
2. Open the file for writing and specify an encoding.
3. Write the string to the file.

Example using Python 3:

```
s = 'ペット用品'
with open('results.txt','w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(s)
```

Your `rows` isn't a Unicode string, but a list with a tuple with an incorrect string.  That's another problem you'll have to solve.

Comment: Thank You, Example you posted works. Now I am able to write Japanese character to files